# Challenges with Exporting DAE in Blender: Missing Alpha Transparency and Mask Image

Tags: transparency, dae

Hello Blender Community,

I've been facing a challenge with exporting FBX files to DAE format in Blender. Here's the situation:

Initial Import: When I import an FBX file into Blender, everything appears correct with the model, including colors, textures, and alpha transparency.

Export to DAE: However, when I import the DAE file back into Blender, I experience issues. It doesn't retain the alpha transparency that the original FBX had. Moreover, not only is the alpha connection missing, but the mask image used for transparency is also not saved in the exported DAE model.

In the export settings of Blender, I haven't seen options related to materials and textures. Perhaps I'm missing a critical step?

My goal is to use the DAE file in the Gazebo virtual environment, but I cannot manually set the alpha transparency in Gazebo every time. So, it's crucial that the DAE export from Blender retains this transparency.

Could anyone offer some guidance or suggest best practices for this process? Are there specific settings or plugins in Blender that can help with this transparency issue when exporting to DAE?

Thank you for your assistance!

Input FBX:
[image]
[image]

Output Dae:

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures